# Xamarin Forms Map - UWP - Zoom Error - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, uwp-maps

I have a super simple Xamarin Forms Map embedded and am running UWP.

```
 <maps:Map
        WidthRequest="320"
        HeightRequest="300"
        x:Name="map"
        MapType="Hybrid"
        />
```

I've noticed that when zooming in and out (quickly) it will error with the following exception thrown:

```
"Value does not fall within the expected range."
```

Any idea what's going on? This is the latest stable version of `Forms + Map 2.3.3.180`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue which affects mainly UWP. Please check [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/pull/724). Should be deployed in an alpha version soon.